# How to avoid logic duplication when promisifying js methods?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, method-chaining

Recently I embraced promises chaining pattern. It's very convenient to do like this:

```
action1
.then(()=> action2())
.then(()=> action3());
```

But, in order to do it I changed all my methods like this (TypeScript):

```
action1() : Promise<any>{
  try{
     // actual code
     return Promise.resolve();
  } catch (err){
     console.error(err);
     return Promise.reject(err);
  }
}
```

This looks like very repetitive pattern. What's the best way to avoid code duplication?

Comment: This hardly makes any sense. Why would you use promises when your `//actual code` is synchronous?

Comment: @Bergi, right. But I want to chain it anyway

Comment: Simply use `action3(action2(action1()))` for chaining of synchronous functions? Or use function composition. You should absolutely not use promises for synchronous code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a function to wrap promise over a function and you can reuse it

```
wrapPromise(fun) : Promise<any>{
  try{
     var value = fun()
     return Promise.resolve(value);
  } catch (err){
     console.error(err);
     return Promise.reject(err);
  }
}


wrapPromise(action1).then()
```

Comment: Yeah, right.  But do people do like this really? What's the best practice.

Comment: @PavelEvdokimov The best practise is not to use promises for synchronous code…

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using typescript, you'll want to use [`async`/`await`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2015/11/). Simply do

```
async action1(): Promise<any>{
  try {
     return // actual code;
  } catch (err){
     console.error(err);
     throw err;
  }
}
```

However there's a good chance you actually don't want to catch, log and rethrow all errors in every function, so this simplifies to

```
async action1(): Promise<any>{
  return // actual code;
}
```

Comment: The linked site says 1.7.

Comment: @Bergi Only if you're targeting ES6.

Comment: Ah, ok. I guess you can target ES6 and then pipe the result through a standard transpiler to anything you need.