# Is it ok to use Maybe<T> and Result<T> types in Typescript/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, functional-programming

There's good mechanism to chain asycn methods in TS: promises.
You can do1.then(()=>...).catch(()=>...).

But what to do if I want to chain synchroneous methods?
In this question [How to avoid logic duplication when promisifying js methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022004/how-to-avoid-logic-duplication-when-promisifying-js-methods#comment69252080_41022004) I was advices **not to use promises** to do it.

In C# I was happy to use Maybe< T > and Result< T > classes to do it.
Any method would return a class **Result**. It would have methods **OnSuccess** (passing result of method into it) and **OnFailure** (passing error into it).

With usage of these classes TS code would look like:

```js
public processAndDouble(input: number) : number {
    return processData(input)
      .onSuccess((processedInput)=>{
        return processedInput * 2;
      })
      .onFailure((error)={
        return 0;
      })
}

public processData(input: number) : Result<number> {
  if(input >= 0)
    return Result.Ok(input + 1);
  else
    return Result.Fail("can't process negative numbers");
}
```

So, the question is, is it ok to use this approach?

Doesn't it contratict to some best practices, principles?

Comment: It's ok as long as you are 100% confident there never will be a single async call in the chain. Once it happens, you'll have to convert everything to promises.

Comment: Thank you, Artem, I like your answer. I'm talking about sync. operations. Hate having them as sequence of variable declarations and assignments.

Answer (score 0):

There is even better mechanism to deal with asynchronous methods in typescript: async/await. So in your case if you will define your root method to be async, you can easily 'chain' together sync and async methods with no extra headache:

```
class A
{
    public async processAndDouble(input: number): Promise<number>
    {
        try
        {
            //Sync method
            let processedInput = this.processDataSync(input);
            //Async method
            processedInput = await this.processDataAsync(processedInput);
            //Sync operation again
            return processedInput * 2;
        }
        catch (error)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public async processDataAsync(input: number): Promise<number>
    {
        if (input >= 0)
        { 
            //Do your async operation here
            return input + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Error("can't process negative numbers");
        }
    }

    public processDataSync(input: number): number
    {
        if (input >= 0)
        { 
            return input + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Error("can't process negative numbers");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you have intuitive mechanism of exceptions still available to you - so there is not need to mess with success/reject handlers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Amid, I can't agree. You propose to rely on try-catch-error mechanism. Result.Fail() has much more meaning then error. It returns "null" results that are awaited and predicted. OnSuccess/OnFailure method force developer to handle situations in caller method. 

Error in js, on the other hand, is like exception in C#. If you forget to handle it - boom - application crashes. Completely different. 

And promisification of synchroneus operations I was adviced agaist before. Though, I don't understant why is it bad. It's like Result class, actually.

Comment: This kind of discussions will get very fast out of scope of the current question. Please bear in mind that this is my personal observations that do not pretend to be absolute truth. I will just note some things you might consider useful. There is no difference between developer forget to catch error or forget to process OnFailure handler - the application will either crash or will continue but with unexpected results, what is better is up to you. On the other hand try/catch with async/await makes code levels of magnitude easier to read and maintain - thus reducing development time and errors.